# Android - Get Google Voice installed languages

Tags: android, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, application-settings

I'm developing an android application that uses SpeechRecognition (Speech-to-text feature). It is possible to detect installed languages in settings through an intent?

Thanks you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, maybe I've found a workaround. In the Intent init, I've added

```
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PREFER_OFFLINE,true);
```

So, when I try to start SpeechRecognizer without the locale language downloaded, app returns

```
SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_NETWORK
```

error. In this way, I'm able to recognize whether a language is downloaded or not.